# JQuery ColorBox plugin - resizing the displayed iframe window

Tags: jquery, lightbox, colorbox

I am trying to use the colorbox plugin to have a lightbox window of another website display, and when I implement it, it has a fixed (small) width/height of display area within a larger (clear) lightbox area window. Nothing I do to the parameters affect the display size of the window containing my display page.

The window displays the website just fine, and the overall area being reserved for the lightbox seems to be correct each time indicated by the positioning of the 'window' in the top-left corner of that reserved area (the rest of the 'reserved area' showing the background content underneath it 100% clear).

Here's my code, hopefully someone can tell me what I'm missing to make this work.

```
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $('.colorbox').colorbox({iframe:true, width:"75%", height:"75%"});
  });
```

the error that I get in chrome is "ReferenceError: m_injectionNode is not defined" repeated 7x if that is useful at all.

Comment: a colleague located the problem - there was a css file located within one of the examples that I needed to include to get it to work - it's working now.

Comment: Same issue: Because the css was not available on the CDN or other hosted sites I made the mistake of assuming the css was not required for it to work. Bad mistake.